# How do I turn a Unicode code point into a Unicode String?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, elixir

I have a string representing a Unicode code point, like `"272d"`. How do I turn that into `"✭"`?

Elixir certainly understands Unicode:

```
iex> << 10029 :: utf8 >>
"✭"

iex> "x{272d}"
"✭"
```

But I need a function that takes in four characters and returns the Unicode String:

```
def from_code_point(<< code_point :: size(32) >>) do
  ???
end
```

or possibly

```
def from_code_point(<< a, b, c, d >>) do
  ???
end
```

I also tried this as a macro:

```
defmacro from_code_point(<< code_point :: size(32) >>) do
  quote do
    "x{unquote(code_point)}"
  end
end
```

But that just returns `"x{unquote(code_point)}"`.

Answer (score 2):

A Unicode codepoint is a number, so the first thing you need to do is parse your string to see what value it represents. You can use `binary_to_integer/2` (available in R16, for R15 you'd need to go through `binary_to_list/1` and then `list_to_integer/2`.

Once you have the numerical value of the codepoint, you can simply plonk it in a binary (which is the underlying representation of a string) by telling elixir that the number you're passing is an Unicode codepoint, like so

```
def to_string(input) do
  <<binary_to_integer(input, 16) :: utf8>>
end
```

if you have to extract it out of a larger string, the you can put `String.slice/3` in between like so

```
def to_string2(input) do
  codepoint = String.slice(input, 0, 4)
  <<binary_to_integer(codepoint, 16) :: utf8>>
end
```

Comment: What exactly is R16/R15 in relation to Elixir? As of v1.3.2, none of the functions exist. Have they been taken out?

Answer (score 0):

I get this:

```
iex(1)> << 10029 :: utf8 >>
"✭"

iex(2)> "x{272d}"
"x{272d}"
```

so I'm not sure if this works. I think you want this:

```
def from_code_point(<< code_point :: size(32) >>) do
  "x{#{code_point}}"
end
```